# Mustache pass parameter from view to function

Tags: mustache

I've the following mustache expression, which works fine:

```
{{#someFunction}}someValue{{/someFunction}}
```

Function block:

```
var view = {
  name : "Bill",
  someFunction : function () {
    return function(val, render) {
      return "I passed in this value: " + render(val);
    }
}
```

What I want to achieve is to make `name` a parameter for `someFunction` like this, but i doesn't work:

```
{{#someFunction}}{{name}}{{/someFunction}}
```

Comment: I'm using the exact syntax, however, the {{name}} is passed as "{{name}}" and does not get interpreted. Is this working for you ok?

Answer (score 0):

There was a typo-issue in the data-model.

```
var view = {
             name : "Bill",
             someFunction : function () {
                return function(val, render) {
                   return "I passed in this value: " + render(val);
                }
             }
           }
```

Otherwise it is working.

Detail: https://github.com/janl/mustache.js#functions

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is, the inline function Mustache calls, inherits the current Mustache variable collection as "this".

```
var _this = this;
template({
                images: imageArray,                                        
                renderImage: function () {
                    return function () {  
// in this you find the iterated one image from imageArray
// when rendering multiple items in mustache using arrays                          
                        return _this.renderRating(this);
                    };
                }
            })
```